# Python calculate how many duplicates I have inside a list with many lists inside them

Tags: python

I have this List :

```
l = [['', 10.0, '', 'Ecran Standard 50"', 'u', '3', 'NEC', 'C501', '21', '', '', '', '', 1.0, 714.04, 2142.12, 1.2, 855.0, 2565.0],
['', 10.0, '', 'Ecran Standard 50"', 'u', '3', 'NEC', 'C501', '21', '', '', '', '', 1.0, 714.04, 2142.12, 1.2, 855.0, 2565.0],
['', 10.0, '', 'Ecran Standard 50"', 'u', '3', 'NEC', 'C501', '21', '', '', '', '', 1.0, 714.04, 2142.12, 1.2, 855.0, 2565.0],
['', 10.0, '', 'Ecran Standard 50"', 'u', '5', 'NEC', 'C501', '21', '', '', '', '', 1.0, 714.04, 2142.12, 1.2, 855.0, 2565.0],
['', 10.0, '', 'Ecran Standard 55"', 'u', '3', 'NEC', 'C553', '21', '', '', '', '', 0.0, 1035.04, 1035.04, 1.3, 1345.55, 1345.55],
['', 10.0, '', 'Ecran Standard 55"', 'u', '3', 'NEC', 'C551', '21', '', '', '', '', 0.0, 1035.04, 1035.04, 1.3, 1345.55, 1345.55],
['', 10.0, '', 'Ecran Standard 55"', 'u', '1', 'NEC', 'C551', '21', '', '', '', '', 0.0, 1035.04, 1035.04, 1.3, 1345.55, 1345.55]]
```

I wanted to remove duplicates but through the reference "C501, C553, C551", then multiply the QTE.

I have this code,

```
count = 0

for ind, ele in enumerate(l,1):
    if ele not in l[ind:]:
        for team in l:
            if team[7] == ele[7]:
                count+=1
        print("{} -> {}\n\n".format(ele,count))
    count = 0
```

But, It removes the duplicate lists, but what I want is remove all duplicates by reference and then multiply them.

Ex:

```
['', 10.0, '', 'Ecran Standard 50"', 'u', '14', 'NEC', 'C501', '21', 'TECHDATA', '', '', '', 1.0, 714.04, 2142.12, 1.2, 855.0, 2565.0]
['', 10.0, '', 'Ecran Standard 50"', 'u', '3', 'NEC', 'C553', '21', 'TECHDATA', '', '', '', 1.0, 714.04, 2142.12, 1.2, 855.0, 2565.0]
['', 10.0, '', 'Ecran Standard 50"', 'u', '4', 'NEC', 'C551', '21', 'TECHDATA', '', '', '', 1.0, 714.04, 2142.12, 1.2, 855.0, 2565.0]
```

how can i fix this?

Comment: I do not see any multiplication. It seems you are adding up the intergers of the values right behind the 'u' ?

Comment: do you mean sum()?

Comment: Change this to a map with the reference you want as a key. Then do your logic on the map

Comment: xszym brought me the solution, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a couple of differ ways to solve this with `itertools.groupby()`:

```
from itertools import chain, groupby
from operator import itemgetter
from pprint import pprint

l = [['', 10.0, '', 'Ecran Standard 50"', 'u', '3', 'NEC', 'C501', '21', '', '', '', '', 1.0, 714.04, 2142.12, 1.2, 855.0, 2565.0],
['', 10.0, '', 'Ecran Standard 50"', 'u', '3', 'NEC', 'C501', '21', '', '', '', '', 1.0, 714.04, 2142.12, 1.2, 855.0, 2565.0],
['', 10.0, '', 'Ecran Standard 50"', 'u', '3', 'NEC', 'C501', '21', '', '', '', '', 1.0, 714.04, 2142.12, 1.2, 855.0, 2565.0],
['', 10.0, '', 'Ecran Standard 50"', 'u', '5', 'NEC', 'C501', '21', '', '', '', '', 1.0, 714.04, 2142.12, 1.2, 855.0, 2565.0],
['', 10.0, '', 'Ecran Standard 55"', 'u', '3', 'NEC', 'C553', '21', '', '', '', '', 0.0, 1035.04, 1035.04, 1.3, 1345.55, 1345.55],
['', 10.0, '', 'Ecran Standard 55"', 'u', '3', 'NEC', 'C551', '21', '', '', '', '', 0.0, 1035.04, 1035.04, 1.3, 1345.55, 1345.55],
['', 10.0, '', 'Ecran Standard 55"', 'u', '1', 'NEC', 'C551', '21', '', '', '', '', 0.0, 1035.04, 1035.04, 1.3, 1345.55, 1345.55]]

MODEL_NO = itemgetter(7)
METRIC_FIELD = 5
```

This will dedup the sublists based on the C501/C551/C553 values:

```
l_deduped = []
for model_no, model_data in groupby(sorted(l, key=MODEL_NO), key=MODEL_NO):
    l_deduped.append(next(model_data))

pprint(l_deduped, width=200)
```

Output:

```
[['', 10.0, '', 'Ecran Standard 50"', 'u', '3', 'NEC', 'C501', '21', '', '', '', '', 1.0, 714.04, 2142.12, 1.2, 855.0, 2565.0],
 ['', 10.0, '', 'Ecran Standard 55"', 'u', '3', 'NEC', 'C551', '21', '', '', '', '', 0.0, 1035.04, 1035.04, 1.3, 1345.55, 1345.55],
 ['', 10.0, '', 'Ecran Standard 55"', 'u', '3', 'NEC', 'C553', '21', '', '', '', '', 0.0, 1035.04, 1035.04, 1.3, 1345.55, 1345.55]]
```

This will dedup the sublists based on the C501/C551/C553 values and perform a sum aggregation on the field after the `'u'` value:

```
l_deduped_and_sum = []
for model_no, model_data in groupby(sorted(l, key=MODEL_NO), key=MODEL_NO):
    template_row = next(model_data)
    model_sums = sum(int(data[METRIC_FIELD]) for data in chain([template_row], model_data))
    template_row[METRIC_FIELD] = str(model_sums)
    l_deduped_and_sum.append(template_row)

pprint(l_deduped_and_sum, width=200)
```

Output:

```
[['', 10.0, '', 'Ecran Standard 50"', 'u', '14', 'NEC', 'C501', '21', '', '', '', '', 1.0, 714.04, 2142.12, 1.2, 855.0, 2565.0],
 ['', 10.0, '', 'Ecran Standard 55"', 'u', '4', 'NEC', 'C551', '21', '', '', '', '', 0.0, 1035.04, 1035.04, 1.3, 1345.55, 1345.55],
 ['', 10.0, '', 'Ecran Standard 55"', 'u', '3', 'NEC', 'C553', '21', '', '', '', '', 0.0, 1035.04, 1035.04, 1.3, 1345.55, 1345.55]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :)

```
l = [['', 10.0, '', 'Ecran Standard 50"', 'u', '3', 'NEC', 'C501', '21', '', '', '', '', 1.0, 714.04, 2142.12, 1.2, 855.0, 2565.0],
['', 10.0, '', 'Ecran Standard 50"', 'u', '3', 'NEC', 'C501', '21', '', '', '', '', 1.0, 714.04, 2142.12, 1.2, 855.0, 2565.0],
['', 10.0, '', 'Ecran Standard 50"', 'u', '3', 'NEC', 'C501', '21', '', '', '', '', 1.0, 714.04, 2142.12, 1.2, 855.0, 2565.0],
['', 10.0, '', 'Ecran Standard 50"', 'u', '5', 'NEC', 'C501', '21', '', '', '', '', 1.0, 714.04, 2142.12, 1.2, 855.0, 2565.0],
['', 10.0, '', 'Ecran Standard 55"', 'u', '3', 'NEC', 'C553', '21', '', '', '', '', 0.0, 1035.04, 1035.04, 1.3, 1345.55, 1345.55],
['', 10.0, '', 'Ecran Standard 55"', 'u', '3', 'NEC', 'C551', '21', '', '', '', '', 0.0, 1035.04, 1035.04, 1.3, 1345.55, 1345.55],
['', 10.0, '', 'Ecran Standard 55"', 'u', '1', 'NEC', 'C551', '21', '', '', '', '', 0.0, 1035.04, 1035.04, 1.3, 1345.55, 1345.55]]

result = []

for x in l:
    value = x[7]
    find = False
    for y in result:
        if y[7] == value:
            find = True
    if not find:
        result.append(x)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(l)
df[5] = df[5].astype(int)
df[5] = df.groupby(7)[5].transform('sum')
df.drop_duplicates()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave the final code there for someone who needs.

```
result = []
calc = 0
b = 0

for x in l:
    value = x[7]
    find = False
    for y in result:
        if y[7] == value:
            find = True
            calc = calc + int(x[5])
            result[b-1][5] = calc

    if not find:
        calc = int(x[5])
        b+=1
        result.append(x)
    
print(result)
```